# absolute center image within Bootstrap Div tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of code that is responsive and i want to center the images both vertically and horizontally. can anyone help me with this puzzling puzzle?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4"><a href="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" target="_blank" title="Read More"><img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"><a href="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" target="_blank" title="Read More"><img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"><a href="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" target="_blank" title="Read More"><img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" /></a></div>
```

Comment: Dunno if you're aware, but the "row" `div` has not been closed. That may affect your page's layout.

Comment: checkout this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/LnMVTmlDc6eNEUyOPonR?p=preview

Comment: I need the bananas to be in the middle of the duck and not aligned to top

https://plnkr.co/edit/bdD3nYnvFPGYoSv9uC3T?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.col-xs-4 {
        display: table-cell;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are very likely to be unhelpful for future visitors and even the OP himself. Consider editing your answer to contain explaination with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `img-responsive center-block` for the images. In this way, the images will be in absolute center and responsive.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" target="_blank" title="Read More"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" target="_blank" title="Read More"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" target="_blank" title="Read More"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/DnbEGqVlOv) for the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: when the tall duck picture is added, the bananas still align to top and not middle.
http://www.bootply.com/K6yYeY8p0w#

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution to this. 
Here is a [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/JJy5QFbnny).
Added this css

```
 .div-center {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.img-center {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the img-responsive (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) and center-block (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center) classes. These are the utility classes provided by twitter bootstrap.

You revised html can look something like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 center-block">
        <a href="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg" target="_blank" title="Read More">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/banana/banana-5.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    ....... Repeat for other divs
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give min-height to every div and set css property like:

```
div{ margin:0 auto;}
```